# Predicting outcome based on previous series

Tags: python, data-science, series, prediction, predictive

I know it's a very naive question, but please any information is welcome.

I have a data series containing 0's and 1's in random order.
Is there any way i can predict the next outcome based on the previous series?

Let's say, there's a website that gives out a value (0 or 1) at equal time intervals, i collect the data from there and i need to predict what value would be posted next. It surely doesn't need to be 100% accurate.

P.S Python solution is preferred

Answer (score 0):

If it's a completely random series, there is no way of predicting the next outcome. That's why it's called random. However, there might be a way. Please provide more information about your problem, like where did you call the random function or a piece of code.

Comment: Let's say, there's a website that gives out a value (0 or 1) at equal time intervals, i collect the data from there and i need to predict what value would be posted next. It surely doesn't need to be 100% accurate.